# ASP.NET MVC 4 Efficiency issue at showing records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, pagedlist

When the Equipo/Index page is requested, it takes between 6-10 seconds to load. I think I might be having an efficiency problem.

Equipo Controller:

```
public class EquipoController : Controller
{
    private ServicioEquipo servicio = new ServicioEquipo();

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string search, int page = 1)
    {
        if (search!= null)
            page = 1;

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = search;

        // Get all "Equipo" records
        IEnumerable<Equipo> equipos = servicio.ObtenerTodos();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            equipos = equipos.Where(s => s.identificador.Contains(search));
        }

        var pageSize = 20;
        IEnumerable<EquipoViewModel> viewModelEquipos = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Equipo>, IEnumerable<EquipoViewModel>>(equipos);

        // Show 20 "Equipo" only
        IPagedList<EquipoViewModel> model = viewModelEquipos.ToPagedList(page,pageSize);

        return View(model); 
    }
}
```

ServicioEquipo:

```
public class ServicioEquipo
{
    private RepositorioEquipo repositorio = new RepositorioEquipo();

    public IEnumerable<Equipo> ObtenerTodos()
    {
        return repositorio.ObtenerTodos().ToList();
    }
}
```

RepositorioEquipo "ObtenerTodos" method:

```
 public IEnumerable<Equipo> ObtenerTodos()
 {
      return base.DBContext.Equipoes.Include(e => e.Cuenta).Include(e => e.EquipoTipo);
 }
```

Equipo View:

```
@model IPagedList<Web.Models.EquipoViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Equipos";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

...

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.idEquipo</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.identificador)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nroSerie)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.primario)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EquipoTipo.descripcion)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cadencia)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.versionFirmware)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.versionProgramacion)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.estadoSd)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cuenta.nombre)</td>
        <td class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.portable)</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.idEquipo })" class="btn btn-info">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.idEquipo })" class="btn btn-warning">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { id = item.idEquipo })" class="btn btn-danger">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

...
```

I think that using the ToList() method might be causing this efficiency problem.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have you profiled this at all?  Measured the performance in any way?  Where you *think* the problem might be and where you *find* the problem to be are two different things.  Lots of external factors *could* cause something to be slow, we really have no way of knowing.

Comment: I know that many factors can cause this to be slow. The way I measured the performance was comparing the time this page takes to load to another page with only 5 records (that takes 4 seconds to load).

Comment: That's a big black box to be measuring though.  There are profiling tools you can use to measure at a much more granular level, even just stepping through in the debugger or logging time stamps to see how long each step takes.  At the moment all you know is that "the whole thing" takes longer than desired.  And you're just guessing which particular line of code may be the culprit.  (Which is all we can do too.)

Comment: All right, I could try that. The purpose of my question was to know if I was making a "huge mistake" that could cause this problem though.

Comment: Possibly, and often worth a cursory check.  Though in this case even such things aren't always so glaringly obvious.  That `.ToList()` *could* be an issue, but if the page is materializing all of the records anyway then it might not be.  Now, if you find that you're materializing tons of records but only displaying a few of them, then that's an issue.  Debugging would determine that.  If after that `.ToList()` the local variable has, say, 10,000,000 items but you only want to display 10 on the page then the `.ToList()` would definitely be an issue in that case.

Comment: I'll test this few things: 1) How long does the repository takes to get all the records from the database. 2) How long does ToList() method takes. 3) How long does ToPagedList() method takes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, you're using a repository but you're not returning a queryable. By calling `ToList()` on `repositorio.ObtenerTodos()`, you selecting every... single... record from the database every... single... time. Maybe that's not such a big deal if you have 100 records total, but if you have 1,000,000 records, well you're going to be there awhile.

Even if you fix the `ToList()` issue, you're never ever limiting the scope of the amount of records pulled from the database. Assuming you actually returned a queryable, the use of AutoMapper to map to a view model would evaluate the query immediately, still selecting every single row.

If you want to use `ToPagedList` for paging, then you *must* pass it a queryable, or in other words, something that has not been evaluated yet. `ToPageList` then applies the appropriate `Skip` and `Take` methods to limit what's pulled. If you evaluate the query before that point (such as by calling `ToList()` or mapping via AutoMapper, it's already too late.

So, if you need to convert to a view model first, what you need is two separate queries. First, you need to get just the records you need (manually, without `PagedList`), and second, you need to get a count of all the relevant records. Then, with those two things, you can utilize `StaticPagedList` to construct your model for paging. Something like so:

```
public ActionResult Index(string search, int page = 1)
{
    if (search != null)
        page = 1;

    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = search;

    // Setup base query - not evaluated
    IQueryable<Equipo> equipos = context.Equipoes.Include(e => e.Cuenta).Include(e => e.EquipoTipo);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        // apply search filter - still not evaluated
        equipos = equipos.Where(s => s.identificador.Contains(search));
    }

    var pageSize = 20;

    // Count of all matching records (hits database, but count is relatively quick)
    var equiposCount = equipos.Count(); 
    // List of current page of 20 records (hits database again, pulls only 20 records, though)
    var equiposList = equipos.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

    // Map just the 20 records to view models
    var viewModelEquipos = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Equipo>, IEnumerable<EquipoViewModel>>(equiposList);

    // Create StaticPagedList instance to page with
    var model = new StaticPagedList<EquipoViewModel>(viewModelEquipos, page, pageSize, equiposCount)

    return View(model); 
}
```

Here, I didn't use your service or repository because those are part of your problem right now. Those are currently unworkable for this scenario. You must either return a queryable or you need to be able to pass in your search filter, and `skip` and `take` params, so that you can properly limit the query before evaluating it with `ToList()`.

Finally, while probably the least of your performance concerns here, `Contains` causes a full-text search using `LIKE`. There's nothing wrong with that per se, but depending on what column type `identificador` maps to in the database, it may cause a slower query. If it's a fixed-length string, you could index it making the query super fast. On the other hand, if it's something like TEXT, it's going to be pretty slow.